# Function clear's everything on output

Tags: python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

The last time the "for loop" in main calls board I want the print to remain

```
import ast
import subprocess
import platform

def clear():
    subprocess.Popen( "cls" if platform.system() == "Windows" else "clear", shell=True)
    return

def pBoard(navn1, navn2, liste):
  print("       1     2     3 ")  
  print("    ----------------- ")  
  print("   1| ",liste[0][0]," | ",liste[0][1]," | ",liste[0][2]," | ")
  print("    ----------------- ")
  print("   2| ",liste[1][0]," | ",liste[1][1]," | ",liste[1][2]," | ")
  print("    ----------------- ")
  print("   3| ",liste[2][0]," | ",liste[2][1]," | ",liste[2][2]," | ")   
  print("    ----------------- ")


def hVunnet():
  print("Hei")

def lTrekk():
   print("Hei")

def iD():
  kor1, kor2 = ast.literal_eval(input("Ditt trekk:"))

def nBrukere():
  navn1 = input("Hva er navnet til bruker 1? : ")
  navn2 = input("Hva er navnet til bruker 2? : ")
  return navn1, navn2


def main():
  liste = [[0 for x in range(3)] for x in range(3)] 
  navn1, navn2 = nBrukere()
  for x in range (0,3):
    clear()
    pBoard(navn1, navn2, liste)

main()
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: You should post the code here on StackOverflow in your question. pastebin will delete it after a while, then your link will be stale and your question useless for the next reader. You can edit your question to improve it.

Comment: Will do in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the subprocess to exit before continuing on to print the last board.  Alternatively, learn what bytes to output to the terminal to clear it (I don't know them offhand) and just do that in your program instead of executing another process for that.

The simplest way is to use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) instead of `subprocess.Popen()`.

Comment: Thx, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run' What am I missing?

Comment: *New in version 3.5*. Closer reading indicates that convenience function is not available in older versions of python. In that case use [`wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait)